# Concat two scripts

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two scripts my component class in vue.js. 
Probably it causes a problem with my frontend.
How can I concatenate it to one working script?
If a problem is with something else, what can it be?

```
<script>
import GETUSER from "@/graphql/getUser.gql"

export default {
  props: ["user"],
  data(){
    return{
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      panels:{
          'X': false,
          'Y': false
      }
  }},
  computed:{

  }
}
</script>
```

And the second script

```
<script>
import PieChart from "@/PieChart.js";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    PieChart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        hoverBorderWidth: 20
      },
      chartData: {
        hoverBackgroundColor: "red",
        hoverBorderWidth: 10,
        labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
            data: [1, 10, 5]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please could you be more clear on what the problem is?

Comment: Using twice <script> </script> app doesn't work. I believe these two scrpts must be concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge the two scripts you would just simply:

```
<script>
import PieChart from "@/PieChart.js"
import GETUSER from "@/graphql/getUser.gql"

export default {
  name: "App",
  props: ["user"],
  components: {
    PieChart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      panels:{
          'X': false,
          'Y': false
      },
      chartOptions: {
        hoverBorderWidth: 20
      },
      chartData: {
        hoverBackgroundColor: "red",
        hoverBorderWidth: 10,
        labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
            data: [1, 10, 5]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note: you have imported GETUSER but don't seem to be using it?